# Invalid file operation exception when trying to read a file in Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql

I need to read a file to a variable in oracle.

I have already created a directory object with read and write permissions.
Oracle is running on windows.

```
CREATE DIRECTORY AUTHC AS 'C:\Users\oracle\Documents\authscript';
GRANT READ ON DIRECTORY AUTHC TO PUBLIC;
GRANT WRITE ON DIRECTORY AUTHC TO PUBLIC;
DECLARE
 vInHandle utl_file.file_type;
 vNewLine  VARCHAR2(250);
BEGIN
  vInHandle := utl_file.fopen('AUTHC', 'common.auth.script', 'R');

  utl_file.fclose(vInHandle);
END fopen;
```

However get the exception saying  "invalid file operation"
*Cause:    An attempt was made to read from a file or directory that does
           not exist, or file or directory access was denied by the
           operating system.

I am not who the oracle user is. Is there any way to find out the oracle user and check permissions

Comment: To rule out the obvious: the (Windows) directory `C:\Users\oracle\Documents\authscript` was created on the server (computer) where the Oracle software is running?

Comment: Yes it is in the oracle server

Answer (score 0):

To find the oracle user, open de task manager and check the "user name" of the process "oracle.exe".

Comment: I have checked the user for oracle and the read permissions for the file are granted. Still the exception occurs

Comment: Re-check that C:\Users\oracle\Documents\authscript\common.auth.script exists and it's OS privs.

Comment: Yes the file and privileges are there

Answer (score 0):

If mentioned file already exists and you want to get rid of this issue being non-oracle user then create the directory from `sys` user and `grant read, write` to `your user`.

```
--login as sys user(owner of Oracle) as sysdba
CREATE DIRECTORY AUTHC AS 'C:\Users\oracle\Documents\authscript';
GRANT READ ON DIRECTORY AUTHC TO your_user; -- replace your_user with user name of the user you are using
GRANT WRITE ON DIRECTORY AUTHC TO your_user; -- replace your_user with user name of the user you are using
-- note: grant to the directory should be given to the user and not the role


--Login with your_user
DECLARE
 vInHandle utl_file.file_type;
 vNewLine  VARCHAR2(250);
BEGIN
  vInHandle := utl_file.fopen('AUTHC', 'common.auth.script', 'R');

  utl_file.fclose(vInHandle);
END fopen;
```

Cheers!!

Comment: When I try to change the user when granting privileges, it says user or role 'ORACLE' does not exist

Comment: So you are trying to say that your user does not exists? What is the name of your user? Just replace it in grant command and execute it

Comment: Yes I did replace. I should replace it with the user which runs oracle right?

Comment: No. You should create directory and grant it from the user who is running oracle. Replace is done with your own user from which you are logged in.

Comment: User who is running oracle - does this mean the user with which we log in to the database or the OS user which runs oracle? Not very clear what you meant by own user?

Comment: ok. so first of all you need `sys` user and `your_own_user`. sys user will create directory and give rights to your_own_user. Then your user will be able to access that directory